# PHP $_GET URL info

Tags: php, function, get

I'm trying to make a script that pulls info from the URL such as `index.php?picid=33409`, and use that number (in that case 33409) to pull up the image that is saved in the database as image number 33409.

However, when I use the code below, it only works properly if  there is a picid in the URL. If there is just index.php then the code shows everything in every single if function (which I don't want it to do) and it tells me that `"Notice: Undefined index: picid"` annoying error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<?php
if(empty($_GET['picid']))
    {
    $set="0";
    }
if(isset($_GET['picid'])) 
    {
    $set="1";
    }
if($set="0")
    {
    // code to do something
    }
if($set="1")
    {
    echo "all set";
    $picid = $_GET['picid'];
    // code to do something completely different using the picid
    }
?>
```

Comment: Rather than using `empty` you can just set `$set` to 0 above the `isset`, then if the `$_GET` value is set `$set` will be changed to 1. Also you should use `else if` - you've already checked if the value is empty, so there's no need to then check with `isset`.

Comment: why isn't the sum total of your code `if (empty($_GET['picid'])) { /* code to do something */ } else { $picid = $_GET['picid']; ... }` ? In addition to the obvious assignment error instead of comparison.

Answer (score 3):

In your if statements you are using the = assignment operator, whereas you should be using the == comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning a value as a boolean condition, instead of having a boolean expression.

Instead of

```
if($set = "1")
```

you should be using

```
if($set == "1")
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do `empty` and `isset`

You could do this with a terniary statement

```
$picid = (isset($_GET['picid')) ? $_GET['picid'] : null;
```

This will set `$picid` to the value from the url if there is one, or `null` if not

Answer (score 1):

Try using `isset` function. this hould be enough.

```
if(isset($_GET['picid']){
   $set=1;
}else{
   $set=0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php):

```
<?php

    if (array_key_exists('picid', $_GET)) {
         $picid = $_GET['picid']
         // code to do stuff with picid
    } else {
         // code to do stuff when no picid is provided
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest changing your code logic to  something like this:

```
$picid = 0;

if (isset($_GET['picid']) {
 $picid = intval($_GET['picid']);
}

if ($picid > 0) {
  //fetch it from the database
} else {
  //
}
```

You assume that there is no `picid` coming from the URL. If there is one in GET params, use the integer part of it (to avoid potential SQL injections). If there is none, its value remains the initial one and you do the other thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($set="0") <-- problem
{
// code to do something
}
if($set="1") <-- probelem 
{
echo "all set";
$picid = $_GET['picid'];
// code to do something completely different using the picid
}
```

those need to be == not =

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!empty($_GET['picid'])) {
    echo "all set";
    $picid = $_GET['picid'];
    // code to do something completely different using the picid
} else {
    // code to do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The notice is obvious. If you are referring only index.php, the if condition will give a notice. Try some thing like

```
if(isset($_GET['picid'])&&$_GET['picid']!=''){
// the other conditions
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use **intval()**

```
$picid = isset($_GET['picid']) ? intval($_GET['picid'],0) : 0;

if($picid)
{
  //do something with it
}
else
{
  //picid doesn't exists
}
```